# Google Tag Manager variable returning null for image URL using DOM Element

Tags: magento-1.9, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to scrape the image url from a product page on magento but I don't know why is returning "null".

This is the URL I'm trying to scrape:

[Chrome Dev Tools Screen with the image URL to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L11Q.png)

After that I checked the selector with the document.QuerySelector() function

[Result of document.QuerySelector on Chrome Dev Tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mL2v.png)

This is how the variable is configured at Google Tag Manager:

[Google Tag Manager Variable Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fqpC.png)

Here is the variable returning "null"

[Google Tag Manager view mode showing variable returing "null"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1bK.png)

I've double checked every step I did and I really didn't find what I am doing wrong...

Comment: How is that image loaded? Maybe this is loaded via Ajax or similar, and it not yet ready at page load (really just guessing, since your setup looks correct at a first glance).

Comment: Eike, thanks for your response! You are probably right. The images are loaded by a function that calls a phtml where there is a another function calling those images by a php script. Considering your theory I can figure this is not getting ready on the page load. My question is: is there a way to check is those images aren't getting ready at page load?

Comment: Well, to fix it I just added an hidden span tag calling the image URL in the file where the page loads. Thanks!